# Como establecer los parentesis en las consultas sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
Select Distinct P.PatientCode, P.LastName, P.FirstName, P.Matrix, P.DOB, 
P.DiagCode1,

P.DiagCode2,P.DiagCode3, P.DiagCode4, P.DoctorCode, 
R.ProgramCode,P.FacilityCode,
P.DiagCode5,P.DiagCode6, P.DiagCode7, P.DiagCode8,
P.Employed,P.RetiredDate,

R.DateFrom, R.DateTo, R.TerminateDate, R.Status, '''' as GroupCreationID 
From MdPt0001 P LEFT OUTER JOIN MdPhPtPg R
ON ( P.PatientCode = R.PatientCode )

AND ( ( (R.DateFrom <= '4/4/2017' ) or (R.DateFrom <= '18/08/2019')  ) And
(R.DateTo >= '4/4/2017' ) And
( ( R.Status in ( 'A', 'T' ) )  OR (( R.TerminateDate  >= '4/4/2017' )
AND ( R.Status <> 'A' ) ) ) )


Where  (P.PATIENTCODE in ( Select Distinct Q.PatientCode From MdPhAt01 Q 
Where 
( Q.ServiceDate >= '4/4/2017' ) 

AND ( Q.Attendance= 'Y' ) AND ( Q.ServiceDate <= '18/08/2019' ) AND ( 
Q.Billed = 'N') OR (Q.Billed is null)))  



AND  Q.CourseCode in ('Code1') 
order by P.LastName, P.FacilityCode
```

En esta consulta da un error que dice lo siguiente:
The multi-part identifier "Q.CourseCode" could not be found

Es como que no reconoce la Q de la clase MdPhAt01, tendra que ver con los parentesis

He comprobado y la tabla MdPhAt01 si tiene un atributo llamado CourseCode

Comment: Faltan parentesis ahi.. el and q.course esta afuera de la consulta que esta adentro del in...

Comment: en realidad no faltan... estan mal puestos...

Comment: Yo creo que tiene demasiados paréntesis, por eso se confunde y no sabe dónde deberían ir

Comment: No podemos hablar de _clases_ en SQL. Supongo que quieres decir el alias de la tabla. Es un tema de visibilidad (_scope_) del alias `Q`, que solamente está definido dentro de la sub-consulta que tienes en el `where`, y estás tratando de utilizarlo fuera de ella, pero allí no es visible.

Comment: preguntaba por eso, pues no se si existe algun formato o una guia estandar a la hora de colocar los parentesis en las consultas, para poder arreglar esta

Comment: En mi opinión, los parentesis deben evitarse en condiciones sencillas y deben funcionar como agrupadores lógicos (sólo uso parentesis cuando uso `OR` o cuando quiero cambiar el orden de operaciones). Mantener un formato con indentación funciona de maravilla para identificar errores de sintaxis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los problemas que tiene tu código es la falta de un formato legible. La legibilidad del código siempre reducirá el tiempo de *debugging*. Lo mejor es mantener suficiente espacio en blanco para hacer notar los bloques que deben ir unidos y los que son independientes entre si. Así podrás darte cuenta de donde colocar los paréntesis y como se relaciona cada parte entre si.

En el siguiente ejemplo, puedes ver como los operadores, las palabras clave y las columnas se mantienen alineados para identificarlas rápidamente. Faltaría darles un alias representativo a las tablas para saber a que se refieren, ya que el nombre no ayuda mucho.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    P.PatientCode, 
    P.LastName, 
    P.FirstName, 
    P.Matrix, 
    P.DOB, 
    P.DiagCode1,
    P.DiagCode2,
    P.DiagCode3, 
    P.DiagCode4, 
    P.DoctorCode, 
    R.ProgramCode,
    P.FacilityCode,
    P.DiagCode5,
    P.DiagCode6, 
    P.DiagCode7, 
    P.DiagCode8,
    P.Employed,
    P.RetiredDate,
    R.DateFrom, 
    R.DateTo, 
    R.TerminateDate, 
    R.Status, 
    '''' as GroupCreationID 
FROM MdPt0001 P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MdPhPtPg R  ON   P.PatientCode = R.PatientCode 
                           AND ( R.DateFrom   <= '4/4/2017'    OR R.DateFrom <= '18/08/2019' ) -- La segunda condición incluye la primera
                           AND   R.DateTo     >= '4/4/2017'  
                           AND ( R.Status     IN ( 'A', 'T' )  OR (R.TerminateDate  >= '4/4/2017' AND  R.Status <> 'A'  ) )
WHERE  P.PatientCode IN ( SELECT Q.PatientCode 
                            FROM MdPhAt01 Q 
                           WHERE Q.ServiceDate >= '4/4/2017' 
                            AND  Q.Attendance   = 'Y'  
                            AND  Q.ServiceDate <= '18/08/2019' 
                            AND (Q.Billed       = 'N' OR Q.Billed IS NULL)
                            AND  Q.CourseCode  IN ('Code1') 
                            )  
ORDER BY P.LastName, 
         P.FacilityCode;
```

Answer (score 7):

El problema es que estas llamando a "MdPhAt01 Q" en dentro del SELECT que es una subconsulta  y no se pueden llamar a **Q** fuera de esa subconsulta, para hacer se pueda acceder a "MdPhAt01 Q" la debes llamar en el FROM o en un JOIN :

```
SELECT .. FROM foo, 
JOIN bar ...
WHERE bar <-- es global
or p = ( select .. from female kiss ) <-- kiss es local no puede salir de los parentesis
or kiss <--- :(  no puedes llamarla
```

**CORRECCIÓN DE CONSULTA**
Ahora es probable que lo que tengas mal son los paréntesis de cierre.

```
Where  (  < --Habre
P.PATIENTCODE in ( Select Distinct Q.PatientCode From MdPhAt01 Q 
Where 
( Q.ServiceDate >= '4/4/2017' ) 

AND ( Q.Attendance= 'Y' ) AND ( Q.ServiceDate <= '18/08/2019' ) AND ( 
Q.Billed = 'N') OR (Q.Billed is null)) *)* <-- este no va aquí  



AND  Q.CourseCode in ('Code1')  ) <-- debe ir aquí
order by P.LastName, P.FacilityCode
```

Comment: por mas que parezca lindo, el concepto de global o local no existe en sql. las consultas son en si mismas consultas. no podes llamar a un campo de una consulta que no existe. Aunque, mas alla de la terminologia, la respuesta es correta